# Cannot save anything in Google API's Drive UI Integration

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

I am using chrome and after clicking Drive API, enabling it, and in the tab Drive UI Integration nothing can save! I've tried refreshing, restarting and on multiple computers.

I type my application name in and change settings, but the save button never becomes enabled.

What is going on? Is there something I am missing. This is so confusing? I cannot proceed because the save button never enables

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The form is garbage and doesn't make it clear what you've neglected to fill out. But, if you read the text in the form you need to upload at least one "Application icon" (not Document) and you need to put in an "Open URL" value. Until you put both those in you can't save any changes on that page.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried clearing cookies and refreshing page?

Perhaps restart machine

If all else fails, you can always take out the batteries then put them back in